# I don't really understand how to get the output for this code

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sum

```
lst = [[2, 3, 4], [1, 1]]
sum = 0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        sum += lst[i][j]
print(sum)
```

I'm new to Python, can you explain how the output is `7`?

Comment: Because you do not count `4`... The `range(..)` of the `j`-loop should be `range(len(lst[i]))`

Comment: Add some print statements to observe the values of `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your loops go over the range of `len(lst)`, while the inner one should probably loop over the range of `len(lst[i])`. The real fix to this, however, is to not loop over `range(len(...))` but to loop over the elements:

```
for sub_list in lst:   # Loop over each list inside of lst
    for value in sub_list:  # Loop over each number in sub list
        sum += value
```

This is cleaner, less prone to bugs like yours, and reads better.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a **bug** in your code:

```
lst = [[2, 3, 4], [1, 1]]
sum = 0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst)): # bug ?
        sum += lst[i][j]
print(sum)
```

What does this mean? That **both** `i` and `j` will range over the *length* of `lst`, which is 2. Thus you will look for the combinations `(i,j)` to be `(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)`. Thus **`(0,2)` is ignored**. A fast fix would be:

```
lst = [[2, 3, 4], [1, 1]]
sum = 0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst[i])):
        sum += lst[i][j]
print(sum)
```

Nevertheless it is more elegant and less error-prone to use `for` loops over collections:

```
lst = [[2, 3, 4], [1, 1]]
sum = 0
for row in lst:
    for element in row:
        sum += element
print(sum)
```

Or you can use the `sum(..)` builtin:

```
lst = [[2, 3, 4], [1, 1]]
the_sum = 0
for row in lst:
    the_sum += sum(row)
print(the_sum)
```